# Generate lists of Webpack code chunks grouped by entry name

Tags: webpack, gulp

I'm using Webpack 4's code-splitting feature. That means for any given entry point, various numbers and names of bundles may be generated.

I want to write that information to disk in a machine-readable format. Ideally, JSON with files grouped by entry file name. e.g.

```
{
    entry1: [
        "entry1.js",
        "vendors~entry1.js",
        "vendors~entry1~entry2.js"
    ],
    entry2: [
        "entry2.js",
        "vendors~entry2.js"
    ]
}
```

If it's any help, I'm using webpack via webpack-stream in gulp.

I plan to use the output data to insert script tags in the pages corresponding with the respective entry files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the status, a json based document and transform that yourself, you are going to have all the needed information. To get that, just run `webpack ... --json`.

You can have it printed on the screen, or save on a file. To save on a file just redirect the output to a file. `webpack ... --json > myfile.json`. Then you can create a script to traverse the json and do the groups you need.

Comment: I had to do a [little extra work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50880737/684776) to get the json file since I'm not running webpack from the command line. But in the end, this did the trick.