# Specify --json in webpack config instead of command line

Tags: webpack, gulp

I'm using Webpack 4 via webpack-stream / gulp. I'd like to write stats as a JSON file, like I would with `webpack --json > stats.json`, but using my current tooling.

Ideally, I would simply set the option in the config object I pass to webpack-stream, but I'm open to other options.

Comment: there is no way to set a json property on webpack config webpack, that is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just so happens I'm using webpack-bundle-analyzer, which provides the option to write out stats.json for me. Here's the config:

```
{
    // ...
    plugins: [
        new analyzer.BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
            // writes to <webpack output dir>/stats.json by default
            generateStatsFile: true  
        }),
    ]
    // ...
}
```

The more general solution is to use [webpack-stats-plugin](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/webpack-stats-plugin).